# jQuery slider not displaying values

Tags: jquery, html, css, uislider, jquery-ui-slider

jQuery slider ain't working. No errors in console, in other questions with similar problem there was a problem with jQuery libraries, but mine are fine, i guess. Also i've checked that libraries are downloading in right order through browser console > network. What should i do?

```js
$("#mockSlider").slider({
  range: false,
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  slide: function(event, ui){
    doSomething(ui.value);
  }
});

function doSomething(sliderValue){
  $('input[type="text"]').attr('value', sliderValue);
};
```

```css
#mockSlider {
  width: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#currentValue {
  width: 15%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

<div>
  <center>
    <h1>Slider</h1> 
    <div id="mockSlider"></div>
    <input type='text' id='currentValue'>
  </center>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: @VXp fixed it in the question, thanks!

Comment: Np, just a side note, the `<center>` _tag / element_ is obsolete.

Comment: but it works now, you've fixed the problem